# Emulator Taking too much time to launch

Tags: android

> The emulator with

- Target -Android 4.2.2(API level 17)
- hw device name 3.2 HVGA Slider(ADP1)

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the Genymotion emulator. You will never look back and save yourself hours of development time. Only drawback I'm aware of is that you cant emulate incoming phone calls. See http://www.genymotion.com/